# Turkish ex-national currently living in Germany without citizenship anywhere

Tags: germany, citizenship, turkish-citizens

To explain the title: due to former political activity opposing the Erdogan administration, my Turkish citizenship has now been withdrawn. I was aware of the looming danger of this happening, for which reason I moved to Germany recently. Now I am faced with this situation:

- I have a residence permit in Germany for about 3 years
- I have no citizenship anywhere in the world
- My passport has been declared invalid by the Turkish government
- I might at some point get indicted for terrorism or something of that sort (my actual crime consists in signing a petition, mind you!)

Now here are my questions:

- How does the state of Germany deal with this?
- Where can I get information about my status? (Which government agency in Germany is responsible for me? Where can I inquire?)
- What are my options to get a citizenship in Europe (or anywhere for that matter) or any secure title of residence?
- Is it possible that I may get deported to Turkey in case of indictment?
- Can I still safely use my "invalid" passport (my only real legal document with a valid EU visa of course) in Germany where necessary, for example registration at another place of residence? Would this be considered fraud?
- To clarify the last question: will the Turkish administration pass the information about them invalidating my passport on to European officials and how will these react?

Comment: Whoa... my best advice is to engage a solicitor for advice, and not get it from random strangers on the Internet. You have too much at stake, and at risk, to do otherwise.

Comment: Has your Turkish citizenship actually been taken away, or was it just that your passport has been revoked? I did find news online about a decree in January that people who do not return within 3 months of an official call to return can have their citizenship stripped, but it doesn't seem like there's been enough time since then for that to happen.

Comment: Regarding international travel if you are stateless, I believe Germany has a travel document for stateless people resident in Germany (Reiseausweis für Staatenlose)

Comment: Further to @user102008's comment, I think you'll have to apply for political asylum to receive a travel document for stateless people, but I should think that if you already have a residence permit it might not be too hard to succeed in that application.  As Dorothy notes, you'll definitely want to get professional legal advice.  If you cannot afford a lawyer (or even if you can) you may want to look for a charitable organization in Germany to help: they may be able to help you find an appropriate lawyer, or even to offer direct legal assistance.

Comment: In my opinion your questions must be answered holistically, not piecemeal. There is some interrelation between them. For this reason I believe you should contact an attorney instead of soliciting opinions on an online forum where people will not have the full picture. All the best.